# Filenames with spaces in the middle of a command (not a while/for loop)

Tags: bash, ls, spaces, pdftk

I'm trying to provide a list of filenames with spaces to pdftk (to merge 3 PDFs into one PDF) but it doesn't seem to like what I'm trying.

```
# pdftk INPUT1.pdf INPUT2.pdf output OUTPUTFILE.pdf
```

It works specifying the files manually:

```
$ pdftk "pdf 1.pdf" "pdf 2.pdf" output t.pdf
$ ls t.pdf
t.pdf (and it works/opens fine)
```

But none of the following seem to work:

```
$ pdftk "$(ls --quoting-style=c | tr "\n" " ")" output t.pdf
Error: Unable to find file.
Error: Failed to open PDF file: 
   "pdf 1.pdf" "pdf 2.pdf" "pdf 3.pdf" 
Errors encountered.  No output created.
Done.  Input errors, so no output created.
```

(note above, not using quotes around the $(ls) fails too)

or this:

```
$ ls -1
'pdf 1.pdf'
'pdf 2.pdf'
'pdf 3.pdf'

$ pdftk "$(ls -1 | tr "\n" " ")" output t.pdf
Error: Unable to find file.
Error: Failed to open PDF file: 
   pdf 1.pdf pdf 2.pdf pdf 3.pdf 
Errors encountered.  No output created.
Done.  Input errors, so no output created.
```

Comment: Assuming you have only 3 pdf files in your directory, then can we try something like `pdftk *.pdf out_file`? Sorry I don't have `pdftk` in my box else would have tested it, please do let me know after testing it?

Comment: `"$(ls --quoting-style=c | tr "\n" " ")"` creates a **single** string of the form '`"pdf 1.pdf" "pdf 2.pdf" "pdf 3.pdf"`', und pdftk will be looking for a **single** file name containing exactly that (namely, spaces and quotes and what not). A similar thing is happening with `"$(ls -1 | tr "\n" " ")"`.

Comment: [Don't parse `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). In this case, the problem is that the shell parses quotes and escapes *before* doing command expansion, so quotes in the output from the `ls` command never get parsed. Really, the solution is to use bare wildcard expressions instead of `ls`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ pdftk "$(some command)" output t.pdf
```

This runs some command, then the double quotes encapsulate the output into a single "word". No matter what the command, the result will be that `pdftk` receives a single argument comprising the entirety of the command's output.

Parsing `ls` is generally considered to be a bad idea.

As suggested by @RavinderSingh13, simply specifying `*.pdf` (or even `*`) may resolve your issue. The shell performs "globbing" to expand the wildcards, and correctly splits them into "words" by itself:

```
$ pdftk * output t.pdf
```

---

If you are running some command other than `ls` that outputs a list of filenames, you need to be a bit careful that you quote at the correct point.

Some portable ways to do this (with some assumptions about command output) are given in the "Application Usage" section of the [POSIX spec for xargs](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html).

On systems with GNU versions of utilities (eg. `find` and `xargs`) a more robust mechanism is provided using non-standared `-print0`, `-0` and related command parameters that assume the NULL character is the (only) special character used to separate items of command output.

Comment: Thanks very much for the input everyone (apologies for marking it answered incorrectly earlier too).

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you want to merge only 3 files at a time, you could try following, I have tested this on Ubuntu system for 3 files(where it handled file names with space too).  You could test it once.

```
pdftk *.pdf output t.pdf
```